# Cordova getting user phone performance

Tags: android, ios, performance, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing hybrid app using Ionic and I do performance testing with one low end budget android device. That phone is my performance quality assurance. Once I upload to the app store, I can see hundreds type of model of smartphone is using my app.

So, I am curious and really want to know how many phone up there that are using my app has a device that is stronger performance than my low end budget device and how many of them were slower. This is something really important for me to further develop and enhance the app. If majority, let say more than 90% of it were faster than my testing device, that mean I am safe to put in more feature into the app. If many devices where below my testing device, that's mean maybe I need to put more concern on performance on future release.

Therefore, is there anywhere I can have those data? Having my own performance test inside my app to do collection? Any API to connect to existing database to have the info of phone performance based on model?

Comment: You can use google-analytics to know the report of your app

Comment: You should try some online service of remote device testing, like testdroid, appthwack or google cloud test lab where you test your app on a lot of different devices.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest: I don't know if there's any existing work you could reuse for that purpose.
But as measuring performance highly depends on your app and the expected bottle necks, I guess that you need to have your own testing methods and that you need to collect your own data. 
One more hint: you could use the [cordova-plugin-device](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) to get information from the phone and OS your app is installed on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But getting phone mobile isn't helpful as there are hundreds or thousands of phone model out there. Simply look at the phone model can tell which grade performance it is. Unless you know every one of it.  Or is there any way to link to benchmark website like antutu and get the data from it?

Answer (score 0):

@user1995781,
I understand your reasoning, however, you are making a fundamental mistake. You assume your Interface is good, when in fact users might reject is. As [Jef Raskin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jef_Raskin) used to say, 'Test and test again'. Jef was the original designer of the Apple MacIntosh.

The point being, you need to test the user experience too.

For your request, you want to Google: [mobile analytics](https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile+analytics)

- Flurry, now owned by Google
- Localytics
- Amplitude
- to name a few

Adobe, IBM and MS all own or have one product in this category. - Best of Luck

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Well I don't assume my interface is good, my point here is about smoothness and performance of the app user will get on their device. Like those benchmark app, usually it will come with the score of your device. Let say the device I use as the requirement of performance test score 1000 mark, then I can assume all device score better than that will have no trouble running my app smoothly. However, those device score less than that might have trouble running my app smoothly. So, I need to collect data how much device are slower or faster than my testing device.

Comment: Hmm.. Yeah I got that in your original post. There are no publicly available databases with that data, that I know of. There are plenty of test facilities, perhaps you can convince them to publish. I too would like to have that metric - if possible. Here is something you might know about [opensignal - Android Fragmentation Visualized](http://opensignal.com/reports/2014/android-fragmentation/) -- If you see anything else I will be highly interested. Here are my public [NOTES](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes)